# Swift: Convert String to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to convert following String to NSMuableArray.

```
var components: String = "library/book/science"
```

For example, I want to perform the following objective c code in Swift

```
NSArray *componentsArray = [@"library/book/science" componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSMutableArray *componentsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:componentsArray];
[componentsMutableArray addObject:@"astronomy"];
```

Comment: change `String` to `NSString` and you can keep using same functions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is your working swift code:

```
var components: String = "library/bool/science"

let componentsArray = components.componentsSeparatedByString("/")     //["library", "bool", "science"]

let componentsMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: componentsArray)   //["library", "bool", "science"]

componentsMutableArray.addObject("astronomy")                         //["library", "bool", "science", "astronomy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var components: String = "library/book/science"
var componentMutableArray = components.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
componentMutableArray.append("astronomy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSString in order to call the componentsSeparatedByString function that will split your text into an array based on the separator of your choice.

```
let theString = NSString(string: "library/book/science")
let components = theString.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
```